# How to make centered HTML page independent from vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website (http://www.rtistree.com) which has vertical scrollbar on some pages. But some pages has not it. Pages content is centered, but when vertical scrollbar appears, it shifts contents a bit left (8 pixels). How to make my content centered independent from vertical scrollbar present ?

Comment: make the width of your content be enough to include the scroll bar,else disable the scroll bar as a whole `overflow-y:none`..

Comment: @VivekChandra How I can make my content be enough to include the scrollbar? Can you provide some example please ?

Comment: the problem is,the content is more than the container -- hence the scroll bar is coming -- but the scroll bar itself takes up some space -- hence the container should be big enough for the scrollbar as well.. making it `overflow:auto` will not solve as the vertical bar will still be present if the content is too big to fit into the container.. it'll be easier if you pasted a sample code with which i can guide you with..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Epsiloncool one solution is to always display scroll.

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common way is to always have the scrollbar:

```
html
{
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Couse if you always have it, the annoying "flip effect" will be away.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options.

set your body to have overflow-y:hidden;

OR

body overflow-y:auto;

The auto will always have the scroll bar present but not active if it doesn't need it, the hidden will remove it always. Best option is to do auto, that will remove the shift of your content.